# Why does "this" only work once in an Aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In an Aura component's helper, you can call other methods like this: `this.myMethod();`.

However, if you do this twice, it doesn't work.

The solution is to assign `this` to another variable as follows:

```
var thisRef = this;
thisRef.myMethod1();
thisRef.myMethod2();
```

Why is this?

Comment: I suspect you have done something in your code that causes `this` to change; e.g. in a callback function that is not defined as an arrow function, `this` won't be the component.